# Using Azure Artifacts as a private Powershell Repository

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I'm trying to determine the best way to create an internal Powershell repository at my company.
We use Azure DevOps so [using an artifact feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/tutorials/private-powershell-library) seemed like a good solution, however the need to have a valid PAT makes this difficult to manage, since any consumer needs an updated PAT to connect to the feed.

Some posts also suggest they had to provide the PAT to install a module from the repository, which would make this even less of a usable solution.

What's the best way to manage the ADO PAT requirements for Azure Artifacts? Even if the token is valid for 1 year it means that yearly I need to go and re-register the PS repository on all machines that want to use it?

From my searches it's possible to use a file share or deploy your own Nuget server, as outlined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/gallery/how-to/working-with-local-psrepositories

However this is yet another thing to manage and maintain, ensure there is storage, that services are monitored... so using Azure DevOps would make this much easier.

Comment: I've spent more than a few hours on this and I can't make it work either.

Answer (score 0):

You get notifications on PAT expirations and can just go in and update it to extend it another year.